# Sentences excluding "being"

Tags: sentence-patterns

I am wondering about a certain type of sentence construction which seems to somehow exclude the word *being*. For example,

> A native English speaker, he was well suited for the task.
>
> Well versed in the English language, he was well suited for the task.

These are different in essence: the first includes the noun in the first sub-clause and the second does not. Are any or both of these grammatically sound?

Comment: From a summary of *To Kill a Mockingbird*... [Chastened, he tells Mr. Gilmer about finding Tom Robinson raping his daughter](http://www.litcharts.com/lit/tokillamockingbird/chapter17). Perfectly normal English, using [word order inversion](http://www.englishtenseswithcartoons.com/inversion_of_word_order_for_emphasis) to emphasise the first part. Not so common in speech though, because it's harder both to produce and to understand.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the first form (the one I am least sure of (as a non-native English speaker)), is it also ok?

Comment: I don't see any significant difference. You can put *He was* in front of *a native English speaker* just the same as *well versed in the English language*. They both look like [adjectival phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectival_phrase) to me, as is the shared component *well suited for the task.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, they are grammatically different.

The first uses a NP (noun phrase) in *apposition* to the subject.

The second uses a AP (adjectival phrase) modifying the subject.

Both are fully grammatical, though many people would, as you suggest, transform them to different kinds of constituent: either an absolute clause (some would say a modifying clause) with "being"  or (in the first case) an adjunct PP (prepositional phrase)  with "as".